# bar chart with 2 hierarchies in x-axis

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, charts

I  have a dataframe that looks like this

```
   SP1-SP2    P1-P2  gmm Fowlkes Mallows  kmeans Fowlkes Mallows
0   AFR-AMR  ACB-CLM             0.883981                0.973784
1   AFR-AMR  CLM-LWK             0.630063                0.649272
2   AFR-AMR  ESN-MXL             0.944129                0.974126
3   AFR-EAS  KHV-MSL             0.916021                0.960642
4   AFR-EUR  CEU-ACB             0.892367                0.911122
5   AFR-EUR  FIN-LWK             0.875518                0.886502
6   AFR-EUR  GWD-GBR             0.934915                0.963250
7   AFR-EUR  LWK-IBS             0.943654                0.974227
8   AFR-SAS  YRI-PJL             0.646557                0.517052
9   AMR-AMR  PEL-CLM             0.993127                0.996963
10  AMR-EAS  CHS-MXL             0.886552                0.924213
```

And I wanted to create a chart with two x-axes, and I didn't find a way to do so.
Here is an example from google sheets
[image]

SP1-SP2 column is the main x-axes, P1-P2 is on each bar.
I don't care if it's with matplotlib or seaborn etc...

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you do something like this?  https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html

Comment: I just tried It, and it looks good.
Do you how I can add the second column ('P1-P2')?
I added the values on top of each bar(like the example you sent), so I can't use it

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understand your question correctly. You want to display 'P1-P2' on the side of the bars like in the image you sent? Is this right or do you want to do something else?

Comment: You got it right

Comment: I am honestly not sure.
I can't see anything mentioned in the examples https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_label_demo.html or documentation https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label